# CSS Animation Not Recognizing Nested Spans

Tags: html, css, animation

I have some HTML, animated by CSS, that nth-child iterates through a list of spans.

```css
/*Body*/
body{
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
/*   white-space: pre-wrap; */
}
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
     color: #222;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: left;
}

.orange{
  color: orange !important;
}
   

/*Vertical Flip*/
.verticalFlip{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 8px;
}
.verticalFlip span{
 animation: vertical 15s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: vertical 15s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: vertical 15s linear infinite 0s;
 color: #000;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 10s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(6){
 animation-delay: 12.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 12.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 12.5s;
}

/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes vertical{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes vertical{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
 
 <h2 class="sentence">
    <div class="verticalFlip">
      <span>1.  Write a Blog post </span>
      <span>2. Click <span class="orange"></span> to open it</span>
      <span>3. ✎ Edit it. </span>
      <span>4. ⇧ Readers upvote best writers</span>
        <span> (✿◠‿◠)  </span>
      <span> ☆</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
  
</section>
```

I nested a span inside a span to color one character orange:

```
Click <span class="orange"></span> to open it</span>
```

Nth-child triggers the spans one by one, but the colored span throws the timing off. I can see an orange flash, but the character doesn't come up in the sentence. I can retime the nth child animations, but I'm looking for a CSS property like 'not', 'ignore', 'skip this span' or 'recognize this span is nested'.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/Mmdboe

Comment: I'll remember to add a snippet next time... That looks awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, it is possible to only target the [direct children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) of an element using the `>` selector. In your case, each instance of `.verticalFlip span` would be replaced with `.verticalFlip > span`. See below:

```css
/*Body*/
body{
 background-color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
/*   white-space: pre-wrap; */
}
/*Sentence*/
.sentence{
     color: #222;
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: left;
}

.orange{
  color: orange !important;
}
/*Wrapper*/
/* .wrapper{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 40px 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
} */

/*Vertical Flip*/
.verticalFlip{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 8px;
}
.verticalFlip > span{
 animation: vertical 15s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: vertical 15s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: vertical 15s linear infinite 0s;
 color: #000;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.verticalFlip > span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.verticalFlip > span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.verticalFlip > span:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.verticalFlip > span:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 10s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

.verticalFlip > span:nth-child(6){
 animation-delay: 12.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 12.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 12.5s;
}

/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes vertical{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes vertical{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
 
 <h2 class="sentence">
    <div class="verticalFlip">
      <span>1.  Write a Blog post </span>
      <span>2. Click <span class="orange"></span> to open it</span>
      <span>3. ✎ Edit it. </span>
      <span>4. ⇧ Readers upvote best writers</span>
        <span> (✿◠‿◠)  </span>
      <span> ☆</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
  
</section>
```

Comment: **This** is how it should be done (beat me by 2 minutes!)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<span>` you can use `<i>` tag.

> Since your are nesting `span`. The nested `span` also inherits the
>   property from parents.

HTML:

```
 <span>2. Click <i class="orange"></i> to open it</span>
```

CSS :

```
i.orange {
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: That works Jyoti. Thanks a lot! Will accept this answer in 6 mins.

Comment: @RubyRube Your Welcome :)

Comment: I would recommend **not** using `i`. The `i` tag has a specific semantic reason. This is not it! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44361895/4665 on how it should be done.

Comment: I think > is probably a better route. By specific semantic reasons, do you mean it italicizes text?

Comment: @RubyRube As per semantic reason it may be correct. I thought it as a icon. Since Font Awesome, Google Icons...etc uses the i tag for it.

Comment: Jyothi Pathania, I thought using i and setting font-style to normal was a clever hack, but it's probably best to accept > as the best practice answer for the future. Sorry if I deprived you of those points. :)

Comment: @RubyRube Yes I agree with you... :)